# How can I decide between two great opportunities/career paths? (and be happy with that decision)

Tags: work-experience, careers, education, career-switch, notice-period

I'm stuck in a situation that my friends and family keep reassuring me is a great dilemma. This whole year, I had planned to go to law school and was admitted to a couple of top 10's. I'm an engineer who wants to pursue IP, and I couldn't be happier with my path up until a couple of weeks ago.

In the midst of my law school decision-making, I was contacted by one of the big Silicon Valley companies that most people would kill to work at. I went through the interview process because the job (as a project manager of engineering projects) sounded interesting to me, and I have always thought that project management might be a good alternate career path for me to law.

So, I found out that I got the job and I will need to make decisions quickly. One small additional tid-bit that I know shouldn't really influence my decision but is something that I'm dreading--if I take the SV job, I will be pulling out the rug from under my current employer's feet, which I'd feel horrible about. They have been supportive of my decision to go back to school but have been planning for me to leave in several months, not weeks.

What do I do? I know a lot of people probably think I sound whiny and everyone keeps telling me that I can't make a "wrong" decision, but I also know that this is a decision that will have a great impact on the course of my life. I'm slightly concerned that the market for engineers in law could shift if I decide to defer my admissions, but I don't know if this is an unreasonable consideration...

Help!

Comment: Strangers on the internet are absolutely the wrong people to help you with this decision. There is no way we can possibly know you or the situation as well as you do. I recommend asking people who you know and trust for advice.

Comment: Thanks @DJClayworth. I realize it's a bit strange to be asking strangers for advice but so far my friends and family haven't been much help (though not for lack of effort).  I was hoping to maybe find someone here that has gone through a similar experience, as I don't really personally know anyone who's had to make a really big career choice between two pretty distinct paths.

Comment: Hey Roy, your question will likely get closed, but if you want advice you can hop in to [chat], and you will likely get a much better back and forth. Link to the question for background, and ask away! Even if it's off-topic as a question because SE is ill-suited for advice, that doesn't mean it's ill-suited for chat. Good luck with your decision!

Comment: Like @DJClayworth said, there's no way for us to give you any relevant advice about this. The only thing I can tell you is to talk to the people close to you (family and close friends) and get their opinion. And remember: it will be an opinion, YOU have the last word. Good luck.

Comment: @Roy Just a note on what jmac suggested, you need 50 rep before you can get into the chat room. in case you're wondering why you cannot get there

Comment: what happened in the end? Are you a JD or in SV? Will we ever find out? I like to think of you painting soothing landscapes, or perhaps running a farm in your neighbourhood, to teach children about ethical food sourcing.

Comment: @bharal - I chose SV and lucked out by also being granted a 2 year deferral from my top choice law school. This is the ideal situation, as it will give me a forced checkpoint to evaluate how happy i am at my job in 2 years. So far I'm really happy with my decision though. And to address your neighborhood farm fantasy--I've actually been volunteering with a kids' cooking school that emphasizes teaching children where their food comes from for a few years now, so I think I hit all the marks!

Comment: @Roy perfection.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to workplace. Wow, what a hard choice to make. All I can offer you is advice based on my experience. I switched career paths a couple of years ago from I.T. support to Programming. I trained in support and went down that path throughout my schooling, always thinking it was what I wanted until I got in the job and realised it was nothing like I thought it would be.

But I taught myself how to program and used to do it as a hobby. I really enjoyed it. I have absolutely no qualifications in programming. What I do have is a job I really enjoy, 2 years commercial experience and more years when it was just a hobby.

For me, the lesson I learnt from all of that was having an education is good; having real world working experience is so much more valuable. I see so many job adverts saying you must have x, y and z qualifications that I could happily apply for without them because I know my experience would back me up. I know I have the examples I can show them of what I have done and what I currently do that will blow anyone with just those qualifications away.

So whilst this answer is entirely based around my own experience, when I see your choice I know exactly what I would do in your situation; in fact it's an easy choice for me. I'd take the job. Several years experience at a Silicon Valley company will do more for your career than any degree. And the fact that you walked into that job without a degree will speak volumes to potential future employers.

Comment: +1 "*... having an education is good. Having real world working experience is so much more valuable.*"

Answer (score 0):

Follow your heart.  If your heart says that you really really want to go to law school, go to law school.  If your heart says that this is an awesome opportunity that you just can't turn down, don't turn it down.  A friend once recommended that I flip a coin.  If I found myself hoping that I would get one answer, I knew what I should do.  If I still found myself torn, then do whatever the coin flip said to do -- it meant that both options were equally good for me.

You're right that your life will be very different no matter which option you take.  Standing at a crossroads is always difficult because you know that your life will change.  Your life is going to change on many smaller decisions.  You might find the love of your life, or your next job, or your best friend while waiting to get a coffee.  Every single decision you make, even just which coffee shop to go into, could impact your life.  Keep perspective: you're going to make many many other life-altering decisions in your life.

Humans are adaptable.  Both paths are awesome.  Whichever path you take, focus on letting that path be awesome instead of focusing on what might have been if you had taken the other path.  Both paths will have ups and downs.  If your life changes in such a way that the path that you are on is no longer awesome, you have the opportunity to make a new path for yourself.  If you choose one path, that doesn't mean that the other path is forever closed to you, or that a new even more awesome path won't open itself up to you in the interim.

Go forth and be awesome.  It's that easy, and it's that hard.

Comment: *A friend once recommended that I flip a coin. If I found myself hoping that I would get one answer, I knew what I should do.* I do this occasionally, except I actually flip the coin and then see if I'm disappointed by the result.

Answer (score 0):

1. What **feels** better: engineer or lawyer work?
2. Experience >>> secondary education

I would take the job at the SV firm, experience trumps education anytime. You can always go to university...

Unless(!) you feel that the experience that the SV job would give you takes you in the wrong direction. In that case that job shouldn't *feel* so attractive to you and the decision should be easy...

Answer (score -2):

You're right, it's a great dilemma!  You have to make a decision: will additional schooling greatly impact your earnings potential?  Put the other way: will you be limited in your job prospects by not having that next level of schooling?

If the answer is that you don't think you'll be limited by not having your Masters or PhD, run to Silicon Valley and start getting valuable experience now!  Your current company, who is planning on you to leave, will still be happy for you.  And you won't be saddled with debt (unless you're really smart and get a full ride) from the additional schooling.

On the other hand, if you think your earnings will be limited by not having a higher-level degree, you have a much harder decision.  Take the money now, build experience with a great SV job; or, go back to school and take the risk that you may come out overqualified for entry-level jobs (or another recession happens while you are in college and the market dries up).  There's still the chance that you may have a good market when you graduate, obviously, so it's not all doom and gloom.

To sum it up, the "bird in the hand > 2 in the bush" proverb is applicable.  You have a dream job on the table.  Do you give it up for the potential of getting a dreamier one later on?